# rates of relatively prime numbers

Tags: number-theory

Given a positive integer $n $ and a real number $1\ge r >0$, we can define two numbers on counting relatively prime numbers:

$\alpha_r^n :=|\{m\in\mathbb {Z}_+|0 <m \le nr, (m,n)=1\}| $

$\beta_r^n :=|\{m\in\mathbb {Z}_+|nr < m < n, (m,n)=1\}| $

And now we can define $\gamma_r^n:=\alpha_r^n / \beta_r^n $.

For example, let $n=10$, $r=0.5$. Then, $\alpha_r^n=2, \beta_r^n=2, \gamma_r^n=1. $

Question: for a given $r>1/2$, how large can $\gamma_r^n $ be? There are many possible answers: for any $n $, there is an upper bound $M $ such that $\gamma_r^n\le M$ or the supremum can be $\infty $. Does the answer differ if the value of $r $ differs?

Comment: Also, do you want the maximum for large enough $n$ (the limit superior), or just the absolute maximum?

Comment: Ah, surely we need to assume $\beta_n>0$ to avoid the trivial conclusion. I want just the max for large enough $n $(or limsup), but it may be helpful to find the absolute max, excluding the triviality above.

Comment: I suspect that the absolute max would probably be when $\beta^n=1$, which is not a very interesting case.

Comment: By the way, the question is probably better phrased as maximizing $\alpha^n_r/\phi(n)$ (where $\phi(n)=\alpha_r^n+\beta_r^n$ is Euler's totient function)

Comment: I think you can probably prove that $\alpha_r^n/\phi(n) \rightarrow r$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ by using the fact that at most one prime factor of $n$ is greater than $\sqrt{n}$, and all other prime factors are less than this. So most prime factors of $n$ grow a lot slower than $rn$, which is linear.

Comment: @D.Lee: Hey, if you put your question back up, I'll answer it. Unless you found your solution already.

Comment: @KyleGannon: umm.. could you post your answer below here? I've re-posted but it's deleted. I'm not used to the policy of math stackexchange.. sorry.